# java netty as tcpServer,delphi TIdTCPClient as tcpClient

Tags: java, delphi, netty, indy

I use the java netty as tcpServer and delphi TIdTCPClient as tcpClient.the tcpclient can connect and send message to the tcpserver but the tcpclinet can not receive the message sendback from the tcpserver .
here is the tcpserver code written by java:

```
public class NettyServer {
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    EventLoopGroup bossGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
    EventLoopGroup workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
    try {
        ServerBootstrap b = new ServerBootstrap();
        b.group(bossGroup, workerGroup)
                .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
                .childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
                    @Override
                    public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch)
                            throws Exception {
                        ch.pipeline().addLast(new TcpServerHandler());
                    }
                });
        ChannelFuture f = b.bind(8080).sync();
        f.channel().closeFuture().sync();
    } finally {
        workerGroup.shutdownGracefully();
        bossGroup.shutdownGracefully();
    }
}


public class TcpServerHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter {
@Override
public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    try {
        ByteBuf in = (ByteBuf) msg;
        System.out.println("channelRead:" + in.toString(CharsetUtil.UTF_8));
        byte[] responseByteArray = "hello".getBytes("UTF-8");
        ByteBuf out = ctx.alloc().buffer(responseByteArray.length);
        out.writeBytes(responseByteArray);
        ctx.writeAndFlush(out);
        //ctx.write("hello");
    } finally {
        ReferenceCountUtil.release(msg);
    }
}

@Override
public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws  UnsupportedEncodingException{
    System.out.println("channelActive:" + ctx.channel().remoteAddress());
    ChannelGroups.add(ctx.channel());

}

@Override
public void channelInactive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {
    System.out.println("channelInactive:" + ctx.channel().remoteAddress());
    ChannelGroups.discard(ctx.channel());
}

@Override
public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) {
    cause.printStackTrace();
    ctx.close();
}
```

}

here is the tcpclient code written  by delphi :

```
  AStream := TStringStream.Create;
  IdTCPClient.IOHandler.ReadStream(AStream);
```

i also use the

```
IdTCPClient.IOHandler.ReadLn()
```

and still can not get the returnDATA.

Comment: Does the communication work if you use a Java TCP client?

Comment: yes  it work if i use the Java TCP client.

Comment: ReadLn requires a line teminator - I see no line terminator in the written data, so ReadLn can't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Delphi code does not match your Java code, that is why your client is not working.

The default parameters of `TIdIOHandler.ReadStream()` expect the stream data to be preceeded by the stream length, in bytes, using either a 32bit or 64bit integer in network byte order (big endian) depending on the value of the `TIdIOHandler.LargeStream` property. Your Java code is not sending the array length before sending the array bytes.

The default parameters of `TIdIOHandler.ReadLn()` expect the line data to be terminated by either a `CRLF` or bare-`LN` terminator. Your Java code is not sending any line terminator at the end of the array bytes.

In short, your Java code is not sending anything that lets the receiver know when the sent data actually ends. Unless it closes the connection after sending the data, in which case you can set the `AReadUntilDisconnect` parameter of `TIdIOHandler.ReadStream()` to true, or use `TIdIOHandler.AllData()`.

TCP is stream-oriented, not message-oriented. The sender must be explicit about where a message ends and the next message begins.

Comment: if i want to reveive  the message from the  tcp server by broadcast ;how should i write the client's code.

Comment: @Alexx TCP doesn't have broadcast capabilities. Please clarify your question. Better yet, post it as a new question, since this question is already answered.